# Keeping same camera view across multiple mobile resolutions

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm creating a 3D mobile game where my base reference screen size is the Galaxy S9, with an aspect ratio of 18:37 (portrait). The player controls a box where you can move +/- 5 units along X axis and objects fall down that you have to either avoid or catch.

That part is easy, the hard part is that when I change the aspect ratio or resolution, the game scale changes as well, and now +/- 5 units on the X axis means my box can be cut off, or completely off screen.

My goal is to limit the camera view so that it always shows the same coordinates no matter the aspect ratio or resolution, within reason (being portrait mode on a phone, obviously don't want to care about it working in landscape or on a PC/Mac).

How can I accomplish this with the minimum amount of stretching or distortion to the game objects? I saw some people show a way to accomplish this for orthographic views, but my camera must be in perspective for this. The default FoV I'm using is 60, and I'm thinking I can try scaling the FoV based on aspect ratio, but I'm at a loss for how to start. Any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Supporting multiple aspect ratios for games is definitely one of the most frustrating things about making a game look professional.

Probably the most common technique is the same technique used by Film, called letterboxing.

[image: Letterboxing Example]

TVs had to solve a problem when widescreen first came out: How do you show a 16:9 film on a TV with an aspect of 4:3? There are two options: either add black bars to the top and bottom of the screen to make the aspect 4:3, or you can make sure that everything important is happening in the middle area that will be shown by both aspect ratios and then just cut off part of the view if it doesn't fit within the aspect ratio.

My suggestion is to surround the playable area with something that looks good, but wont affect the game if it gets cut off. Then write a routine that will run when your level loads for your camera to zoom out until all of the play area is visible. Since you zoomed out, this means that devices which do not have the same aspect ratio as your play area will be able to see the area around the play area. As long as you have non-play area that is big enough, there won't be an issue.

Here are some good examples:[image: Black Bars][image: Extra Play Example]

Note: Sorry the examples are orthographic, but the same should work for perspective, you just may have to be a little creative with doing a projection from the camera frustrum to determine if your play area is all visible